# How can I do a multiplication of images (by pixels)?

Tags: image

How can I do a multiplication of images (by pixels)?

```
Bitmap first = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
Bitmap second = ProcesarImagen.SetImageOpacity(pictureBox2.Image, 0.5f);
Bitmap result = new Bitmap(Math.Max(first.Width, second.Width), Math.Max(first.Height, second.Height));
Console.WriteLine(first.Width);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
g.DrawImageUnscaled(first, 0, 0);
g.DrawImageUnscaled(second, 0, 0);
pictureBox3.Image = result;
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language being used. Java?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?